# jquery - how to make highlight function

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation and one of the buttons needs to be highlighted!

It needs to have `font-weight: 600;` and after **2 seconds** it goes back to `font-weight: 0;` and it repeats all the time - time between "font-weight" changes is 2 seconds. How to make a loop?

Comment: show some code how you are doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `toggleClass()` inside an `interval`:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ecasiw/2/edit)*

CSS:

```
.bolded{
  font-weight:600;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function toggleBold(){
  $('a.active').toggleClass('bolded');
}

setInterval(toggleBold, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeFontWeight() {
 var fontWeight = $('#buttonID').css('fontWeight');
 if(fontWeight == '600') { 
   $('#buttonID').css('fontWeight', 0);
 } else { 
   $('#buttonID').css('fontWeight', 600);
  }
}



 setInterval(changeFontWeight,2000)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval("var fontWeight = $('#buttonID').css('fontWeight'); if(fontWeight == '600') { $('#buttonID').css('fontWeight', 0); } else { $('#buttonID').css('fontWeight', 600); }", 2000);
```

I haven't tested it, but that's the general theory